# How does Angular build a module

Tags: angular, module

For example we have a `shared` module that contains a bunch of input components, that are widely used in my app.

Under the shared module I have

`input.component.ts`
`checkbox.component.ts`
`datepicker.component.ts`
and etc.

So lets say I have another `page` component, that belongs to its own `page` module, where I want to insert one of the components above. In order to do this I have to import the whole `shared` module, right?

Is there any difference in terms of performance, whether I import the whole `shared` module, while I need only one component from a dozen, or it is better to have an independent module for each low-level component, so I can import only that exact component I need.

I am curious how Angular deals with it, thank you.

Comment: In theory, webpack should tree shake away anything that's not used anyway. I don't know how closely the practice follows the theory, though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how big angular libraries work (e.g. angular material, angular itself), I think that Angular include in the bundle all the module code. That's why you have different modules that you import when you need, and not just one big module that exports all.

So yes, from a bundle size point of view it would be better to have one module for each shared component. Of course, that's overkill in my opinion: we are talking of Kb which, in most applications, doesn't make a difference.

**The best advice is going by semantic and your gut**: I would say just start by using a shared module with all the shared components, then if you feel that some components are strongly correlated to each other (e.g. form inputs) and not used everywhere, create a module at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can Load the Whole Module but you specify an exact component that you use in another module like you need to make one index.ts file and then export the exact component from the shared module :

```
export * from './components/check-box/check-box.component';
```